# Remove gap from odd-rowed flexbox multi-line content

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a grid of product tiles I'm displaying with flex to be equal height based on this codepen: https://codepen.io/imohkay/pen/gpard
They are 3-wide. However, on the last "row" when there is only 2 tiles left, the last tile gets pushed to the right as if there were 3 tiles. I can't figure out the right css setting to make it be in the second column.

Screenshot: https://pasteboard.co/Hk699jP.png

```
#products {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-content: stretch;
}

.product {
    width: 33.3%;
}
```

Comment: Share your HTML too.

Comment: Use justify-content: flex-start and add margin at the right side of the flex items.

Comment: What I see in you codepen is different from the image and the last row boxes are align to the left in your code

Answer (score 0):

They're pushed from each-other because you're using the `space-between` option on the `justify-content` property.

Either change `space-between` to `flex-start` or switch the `display` to a `grid` layout.

Fiddle (`flex-box` https://jsfiddle.net/swordys/db7dzkcx)

Fiddle (`grid` https://jsfiddle.net/swordys/65cyr3tu/)